# How to disable Orders and Returns: "/sales/guest/form/"

Tags: magento-1.7, php

I notice that magento 1.7 offers an option on the frontend where customers can look up their orders using email, order number and billing name.
The form is usually located here:

```
domain.com/sales/guest/form/
```

Any ideas how can I disable this option? Not necessarily delete it from the footer, but actually disable this option.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered in pretty good detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625352/how-to-remove-magento-orders-and-returns-page

Another alternative would be to do a URL redirect in Magento admin: Catalog > URL Redirects. We ended up doing this due to exploit attacks.